# Problemas(ou nao) com a IDE do Xamarin no Mac OSX

Tags: xamarin-studio

Boa noite pessoal
Instalei o Xamarin Studio Version 5.10.3 (build 51).
Sou programador .NET e estou tentando fazer uma coisa bem ridícula e básica.
Uma pagina web forms, so que a barra de ferramentas pra visualização modo design nao funciona. Isso no Visual Studio é básico. Vc cria um projeto e ele te abre o modo visual pra vc inserir os "objetos" de forms. Nao consigo ter isso no Xamarin e nao acho nenhum tópico na internet a respeito. Desde o Mono Developer que nao consigo, sempre por essa razao, deixo de usar o .NET no meu mac por achar que é bug ou algo do tipo.

Alguém pode me dar um help, por favor?
Meu mac ta zuado? É assim mesmo no Mono?

[image: Print da minha tela]

Comment: Esse não é o propósito do `Xamarin` não é aplicações web e sim aplicações nativas com `C#`, nada de `html`, `css`, etc.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário. Mas eu consigo escrever todos os codigos de um botao acessando uma funcao normalmente e dar um build no projeto e rodar no meu navegador. Entao, ele funciona pra web. Nao entendi somente sua colocacao de que ele nao é pra aplicacoes web, ja que ele cria solucoes ASP.NET

Comment: Desculpa, eu confundi com a `IDE Xamarin` para smartphones e tablets.

Comment: Magina amigo. Sem problemas. :D

Comment: Você quer ter o editor visual para o Xamarin?

Comment: Quero que os objetos, tipo botões, caixas de texto, apareçam na minha barra de ferramentas como aparece no VS/Windows...coisa básica que a IDE deveria apresentar.

Answer (score 0):

Olá @David Chinellato, infelizmente o Xamarin Studio, não possui suporte ao ASP.NET Visual Designer.

Abraço.